# TinySort not sorting by correct attribute

Tags: javascript, tinysort

I have a ul with il's I want to sort with the push of a button. I have two buttons for this. One to sort on attr:id and one to sort on attr:name.

And this works! Great!

The ul will be cleared and appended from a different script. This is done every 30 seconds and is needed to update the data.

In order to keep the choosen sorting method I set a value to 0 or 1 when one of the buttons is clicked.

**The Problem** is that after appending the ul and running a function to sort the list in the requested order the list is sorted on attr:name where it should have been attr:id.

What do I need to do to correct this behaviour?

This works and looks like this;

```
<ul class="list-group" id="standstill">
    <li class="list-group-item" id="141" name="4"></li>   
    <li class="list-group-item" id="145" name="5"></li>  
    <li class="list-group-item" id="45" name="6"></li>  
    <li class="list-group-item" id="231" name="4"></li>  
    <li class="list-group-item" id="1441" name="4"></li>  
    <li class="list-group-item" id="841" name="3"></li>  
</ul>
```

and the buttons are like this;

```
<button id='toggle_standstill_time' onclick="toggleSort_standstill_time()"></button>
<button id='toggle_standstill_prio' onclick="toggleSort_standstill_prio()"></button>
```

and the scripting to trigger the sorting is like this;

```
  function toggleSort_standstill_time() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('#toggle_standstill_time');
    if (btn.classList.toggle('desc')) {
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'desc',
        attr: 'id'
      });
    btn_standstill_time = 1;
    } else {
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'asc',
        attr: 'id'
      });
    btn_standstill_time = 0;
    }
  }
  function toggleSort_standstill_prio() {
    var btn = document.querySelector('#toggle_standstill_prio');
    if (btn.classList.toggle('desc')) {
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'desc',
        attr: 'name'
      });
    btn_standstill_prio = 1;
    } else {
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'asc',
        attr: 'name'
      });
    btn_standstill_prio = 0;
    }
  }
```

And the function to order the list after a timed refresh of the data;

```
function orderlist(){
    if(btn_standstill_time == 1){
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'desc',
        attr: 'id'
      });
    }
    else{
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'asc',
        attr: 'id'
      });
    }
    if(btn_standstill_prio == 1){
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'desc',
        attr: 'name'
      });
    }
    else{
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'asc',
        attr: 'name'
      });
    }   
}
```

The result I get for when

```
btn_standstill_time = 1
```

after a refresh looks like this;

```
<ul class="list-group" id="standstill"> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="841" name="3"></li> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="141" name="4"></li> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="231" name="4"></li>  
    <li class="list-group-item" id="1441" name="4"></li>  
    <li class="list-group-item" id="145" name="5"></li>  
    <li class="list-group-item" id="45" name="6"></li>    
</ul>
```

Where I had expected for

```
btn_standstill_time = 1
```

to get;

```
<ul class="list-group" id="standstill"> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="45" name="6"></li> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="141" name="4"></li> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="145" name="5"></li> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="231" name="4"></li> 
    <li class="list-group-item" id="841" name="3"></li>   
    <li class="list-group-item" id="1441" name="4"></li>     
</ul>
```

I would appriciated any help offered!

Best regards,

Ruud

Comment: Have you _verified_ that this variable actually contains 1 inside your orderlist function, or did you just assume it should?

Comment: I have indeed checked that. A console log returns the expected value in the 'reload' function.

Answer (score 0):

If found the error. I used an if/else statement for the various button states. I changed this into a if statement per state (switchting between 0 an 1) and changed the operator == into === and now it works.

used solution below;

```
function orderlist(){
    if(btn_standstill_time === 1){
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'desc',
        attr: 'id'
      });
    }
    if(btn_standstill_time === 0){
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'asc',
        attr: 'id'
      });
    }
    if(btn_standstill_prio === 1){
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'desc',
        attr: 'name'
      });
    }
    if(btn_standstill_prio === 0){
      tinysort('ul#standstill>li', {
        order: 'asc',
        attr: 'name'
      });
    }   
}
```